# offline JSON tester

Tags: json, testing

I need to test a web application which is running on an internal test server. The application is not outputting JSON because I have not changed the accept header to application/json. Is there any json test application which can run on your computer?

Comment: Why have you not changed the accept header? You could always use `curl` or equivalent and force the accept header to be JSON, store the result into a file that you could then parse or view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I'm using `soapUI 4.5.1` for testing json. For more information, you can find out at http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add this plugin to your chrome `JSON Prettifier` [JSON Prettifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-prettifier/kccpfgilgmgbipamhohknpokhibinhhj?utm_source=plus)

If you can manage to let your web app post your result on the browser, it will format it for you and tell you if it's not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I need. My web app produces html if it does not receive the accept header as application/json.